# How to return values from an event handler in a promise?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, typescript

I am building a nodeJS app which uses the [`nodegit`](https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit) npm package. So based on the example in their docs, I have the following chapter. It uses a chain of promises, with what looks like a JQuery event handler. Here is my function:

```
export function prepareDiffs() {
    var patt = new RegExp('[0-9].[0-9]');
    var results: Array<Commit> = [];
    Git.Repository.open("features/tutorial") // Open the repository directory.
        .then(function (repo) { // Open the master branch.
            return repo.getMasterCommit();
        })
        .then(function (firstCommitOnMaster) { // Display information about commits on master.
            var history = firstCommitOnMaster.history(); // Create a new history event emitter.

            history.on("commit", function (commit) { // Listen for commit events from the history.
                var entry = new Commit();

                entry.hash = commit.sha();
                var step = patt.exec(commit.message());

                if (step !== null) {
                    entry.step = step.toString();
                }
                results.push(entry);
            })
            history.start(); // Start emitting events.
            console.log("return");
        });
}
```

So putting console.log in the `history.on()` event handler shows all the info I would want to see. So I am fairly confident in my array pushes. So how can I get the `prepareDiffs()` function to return the populated `results` array or at least a promise which resolves to the array?

NB: I am using Typescript targeting es6, so async/await is useable.

Answer (score 4):

Have your second `then` callback create and return a promise, then listen for the `end` event and resolve the promise at that point with your array, see the `***` comments:

```
export function prepareDiffs() {
    var patt = new RegExp('[0-9].[0-9]');
    var results: Array<Commit> = [];
    // *** Note we're returning the result of the promise chain
    return Git.Repository.open("features/tutorial") // Open the repository directory.
        .then(function (repo) { // Open the master branch.
            return repo.getMasterCommit();
        })
        .then(function (firstCommitOnMaster) { // Display information about commits on master.
            // *** Create and return a promise
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                var history = firstCommitOnMaster.history(); // Create a new history event emitter.

                history
                    .on("commit", function (commit) { // Listen for commit events from the history.
                        var entry = new Commit();

                        entry.hash = commit.sha();
                        var step = patt.exec(commit.message());

                        if (step !== null) {
                            entry.step = step.toString();
                        }
                        results.push(entry);
                    })
                    .on("end", function() { // *** Listen for the end
                        // *** Resolve the promise
                        resolve(results);
                    });
                history.start(); // Start emitting events.
                console.log("return");
            });
        });
}
```

I want to emphasize that **most of the time, you don't want to create new promises** when you're already dealing with a promise-based API. But in this case, because you're getting a series of async `commit` events from the event emitter `history()` returns, you can't directly use the promise chain, so creating a promise is okay here.

Note *when* we create it. We do it there so that if the promise returned by `Git.Repository.open` or `getMasterCommit` rejects, the caller sees that rejection.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version that makes use of async/await.
You can use await to call any function that returns a Promise.
Note prepareDiffs returns a Promise that wraps the event emitter.

```
    export function prepareDiffs(): Promise<Commit[]> {
        return new Promise<Commit[]>(async (resolve, reject) => {
            var repo = await Git.Repository.open("features/tutorial");
            var masterCommit = await repo.getMasterCommit();
            var history = masterCommit.history();
            var result: Commit[] = [];
            history.on("commmit", commit => {
                var entry = new Commit();
                entry.hash = commit.sha();
                var step = /[0-9].[0-9]/.exec(commit.message());
                if (step !==  null)
                    entry.step = step.toString();
                result.push(entry);
            });
            history.on("end", () => resolve(result));
            history.on("error", err => reject(err));
            history.start();
        });
    }
```

Call it like this...

```
var commits = await prepareDiffs();
```